# jQuery: Remove class if other element is clicked

Tags: jquery, addclass, toggleclass

I have an ul-list that contains li-elements. When the user clicks on one of these li elements a class should be added to that element.

This is easy to setup, however, when the other li-element is clicked I want the "active"-class to be removed from the non-active li.

I have made a jsfiddle of the problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/tGW3D/

There should be one li-element that is red at any one time. If you click the second and then the first, only the first should be red.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

This will remove the active class from each li that have active and than will add to the Element which was clicked.

```
$('body').on('click', 'li', function() {
      $('li.active').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: it is not working for dynamically generated li. Need help.

Comment: @ppmakeitcount I updated it to cover also similar cases

Answer (score 24):

You can use `siblings` and `removeClass` methods.

```
$('li').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lb65e/

Answer (score 5):

Just remove all instances of `.active` first, and then add it:

```
$('ul li').on('click', function() {  
    $('ul li.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');    
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('li').click(function() {
  $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Check:
http://jsfiddle.net/tGW3D/2/

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/c7ZE4/

You can use the siblings function. [addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) returns the same jquery object $(this) so you can chain the [siblings](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) method which returns all the other elements except $(this).

```
 $('li').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
 });
```

Comment: I see now that i wasnt alone in this one :D Anyways this can be a one liner.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('li').click(function() {
      $(this).addClass('active'); // add the class to the element that's clicked.
      $(this).siblings().removeClass('active'); // remove the class from siblings. 
});
```

If you know jquery you can chain it like below.

```
 $('li').click(function() {
      $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active'); 
});
```

Above code will do the trick for you. [Try this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Gy39P/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('li').click(function() {
            $("li.active").removeClass("active");
                $(this).addClass('active');
            });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: You can improve the answer by providing explanation of what you do

Answer (score 0):

```
  $(document).on('click','ul li',function() {
        $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    });
```

This jquery code might help.
Don't forget to add [Jquery CDN](https://code.jquery.com).

Answer (score 0):

You may use following code:

```
$('document').on('click', 'ul li', function() {
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass("active") ;
});
```

Comment: In addition to your code snippet, it would be nice if you could explain what is happening. Even though for most people it's self-explanatory, I'm sure there are people who would be glad if some explanation is included. Also pleas format your answer so it's more readable (add it into a code block and maybe add line breaks)

Answer (score -1):

You change css class by this code:

```js
$('li').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active'); 
});
```

Link to [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/salmanaziz/1a7L6tqn/9/)

Comment: Thanks, but the question has been answered for 4 years. :)